# What is the Galois group of this extension?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $u$ be the real root of $x^3-x+1$; I am trying to calculate de Galois group of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)/\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$; let's start with the first one; as $x^3-x+1$ is monic, and irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (just checking that $0$, $1$ and $2$ are not roots of the polynomial), and $u$ is root of the polynomial, $x^3-x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. So, $[\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u):\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}]=3$ (the degree of the extension), being possible to choose $\{1,u,u^{2}\}$ as a basis for the extension. Then, we proceed to calculate the Galois group, i.e., $G=Aut_{\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$ (the group of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$). We can conclude that we can define every automorphism by the image of $u$, and if $\varphi \in G$, $\varphi(u)$ is root of the minimal polynomial of $u$ ($x^3-x+1$); of course, some minor proofs have to be given in order to justify this assumptions. The only root of the polynomial that is in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$ is $u$, as the other $2$ are complex roots, so the only automorphism possible is the identity, that sends $u$ to $u$. So, $G=\{Id\}$, and $G'$ (i.e, ''what the automorphisms on $G$ fix from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$ '') is $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$, and as $G'$ is different from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the extension is not a Galois extension.
Is this sketch of my way of thinking the exercise ok? And, If I change $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$ with any $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}(u)$, with $n$ prime, does the exercise will still have analogous results? Thanks in advance for your time!

**Important remark** Every time I write $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)/\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ I am refering to $[(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})(u)]/(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$, i.e., the extension $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})(u)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What do “complex roots” mean for a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3$? Also, you may want to read up on finite fields a bit, as they always have an interesting nontrivial automorphism.

Comment: @Mindlack oh ok I am reading now and I am seeing how far was I from getting the thing. I am reading about the Frobenius map... So, taking the Frobenius map $F(r)=r^3$ in this case, and then $H(r)=(r^3)^2$ as well as the identity will give me $G$, and the extension will be Galois... But this means that $F(u)$ is a root of $x^3-x+1$, as well as $H(u)$... I am not getting this as well as how can I get here in a more or less systematic way. Thanks!

Comment: "$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)/\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$" desperately needs parentheses to disambiguate meaning.  Is this an iterated triple quotient?  Is this a quotient of quotients?  Is this a quotient by an iterated double quotient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the other two roots of $x^3-x+1$ lie in the field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}(u)$.  Explicitly the three roots are $u,u+1,u-1$.  It is easy to see that the automorphism $\varphi\colon u\mapsto u+1$ has order $3$ and thus generates the Galois group.

In general, given an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ over a finite field $GF(p^k)$, if we attach a single root $u$, we obtain $GF(p^{kd})$.  This sits inside the splitting field of the polynomial.  However any other root generates a subfield of the same size, and as there is a unique subfield of size $p^{kd}$ (namely the set of solutions to $x^{p^{kd}}=x$), all roots generate the same subfield.

We conclude that $GF(p^{kd})$ is already a splitting field for the polynomial.

Comment: How are you getting that $u+1$ and $u-1$ are the other roots of $x^3-X+1$? Thanks for answering @tkf !

Comment: Just substitute into the polynomial.  Note modulo $3$ we have $(u+1)^3=u^3+1$ and $(u-1)^3=u^3-1$, which reduces the calculation considerably.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it! And why we obtain $GF(p^{kd})$ there (where you mention it)? I don't understand exactly how that works... You are saying that $GF(p^{k})(u)=GF(p^{kd})$?

Comment: Yes, if you attach a root of an irreducible degree $d$ polynomial, then you get a $d$-dimensional extension.  Of course $(p^k)^d=p^{kd}$.